# 'Unable to cast the type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.'

Tags: vb.net, winforms, linq

In trying to retrieve info from my database using linq but it won't work. When i excecute the code it throws the exception "'Unable to cast the type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.'

```vb
Public Class HomeTree
    Inherits ApplicationFolders

    Private _CanList As Boolean
    Public Property CanList() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _CanList
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            _CanList = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _CanEdit As Boolean
    Public Property CanEdit() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _CanEdit
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            _CanEdit = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _CanAdd As Boolean
    Public Property CanAdd() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _CanAdd
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            _CanAdd = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _CanDelete As Boolean
    Public Property CanDelete() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _CanDelete
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            _CanDelete = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Retrieving Data

```vb
Dim GBItems As List(Of HomeTree) = (From t In db.ApplicationFolders
                                            Join r In db.AppFolderRoleConfig On {t.AppFolderId, isLoggedInUser.ID_Role} Equals {r.AppFolderID, r.RoleID}
                                            Where t.ParentID = 0 AndAlso t.TypeID = 1 Select New HomeTree With {
                                                                                          .ID_Key = t.ID_Key,
                                                                                          .AppFolderId = t.AppFolderId,
                                                                                          .Name = t.Name,
                                                                                          .Active = t.Active,
                                                                                          .Description = t.Description,
                                                                                          .ParentID = t.ParentID,
                                                                                          .TypeID = t.TypeID,
                                                                                          .CanAdd = r.CanAdd,
                                                                                          .CanDelete = r.CanDelete,
                                                                                          .CanEdit = r.CanEdit,
                                                                                          .CanList = r.CanList
                                                                                          }).ToList()
```

Ive tried googling for my issue but i cannot figure it out.

[Image to show what happens if i try answer given.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lfe6.png)

[Error Msg.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ayuy.png)

Comment: Please format your code properly BEFORE you click the submit button. You are provided with a preview for a reason.

Comment: also, which filed type is Guid: AppFolderID, .RoleID ? mabe missing cast?

Comment: @PowerMouse AppfolderiD is Guid and RoleID is integer

Answer (score 0):

try this query example. since i dont know your db structure (was not provided) and data example i assumed on my own.
i think this is what are you looking for

```
New With {Key.a = af.AppfolderiD.Value, Key.v = isLoggedInUser_ID_Role}
```

code

```
    Dim isLoggedInUser_ID_Role As Integer = 1

    Dim GBItems = (
        From af In ApplicationFolders
        Join ar In AppFolderRoleConfig On
            New With {Key.a = af.AppfolderiD.Value, Key.v = isLoggedInUser_ID_Role} Equals 
            New With {Key.a = ar.AppFolderID.Value, Key.v = ar.RoleID.Value} 
    Where af.ParentID = 0 AndAlso af.TypeID = 1 
    Select New HomeTree() With {
        .ID_Key = af.ID_Key,
        .AppFolderId = af.AppfolderiD,
        .Name = af.Name '...
    })
    GBItems.Dump()
```

add image to prove that code is works

[image]